# Google Colab Cell Formatting

Tags: google-colaboratory

Hi I'm printing out data, and there is so much space in my cell. Google Colab, however,  prints the "exited" column in the next line. How do I force Colab to print it in the same rows as the other fields, i.e. beside number_of_employees. Thanks!

[image: Output where exited column is shown in next line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colab includes an extension that renders pandas dataframes into interactive displays that can be filtered, sorted, and explored dynamically.

using `data_table` method defined in google.colab extension, You can expend Google Colab print result

```py
from google.colab import data_table
data_table.enable_dataframe_formatter()
```

you Add upper code in your First Cell,
Colab's print result is expended

and You want to disabled that function,

```py
data_table.disable_dataframe_formatter()
```

you can use upper code what I write

Comment: Thanks @Notepad. I tried from google.colab import data_table
data_table.enable_dataframe_formatter()
print(attrition_past.head()) but it outputs the same thing. Or I am not getting what you mean? Thanks again

Comment: from IPython.display import Javascript display(Javascript('''google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(0, true, {maxHeight: 5000})'''))        Please try this script? Eventually you should use IPhython.display if you didn't work my solution @newbiepy

Comment: Thanks again @Notepad. Unfortunately still did not change: from IPython.display import Javascript 
display(Javascript('''google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(0, true, {maxHeight: 5000})'''))
print(attrition_past.head())

Comment: Hi Notepad...I worked on the leads you made and was able to make it work...from google.colab import data_table
data_table.DataTable(attrition_past, include_index=False, num_rows_per_page=10)! Appreciate very much your help! Thank you!!!

Comment: I glad to hear that you resolve your question!
Have a good coding work byby